# Finding a string with AWK before or after an iteration of a repeated sequence

Tags: awk, ffmpeg

So I've got a text document that looks like this (truncated)

```
[FRAME]
pkt_pts_time=0.000000
pict_type=I
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
pkt_pts_time=0.250250
pict_type=B
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
pkt_pts_time=0.500500
pict_type=P
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
pkt_pts_time=0.750750
pict_type=B
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
pkt_pts_time=0.959292
pict_type=I
[/FRAME]
```

This text was created with this command:

```
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time,pict_type,frame_number -v quiet input.mp4
```

As you can see, the [Frame] to [/Frame] sequence is repeated.  So this is a way for me to count the frames and find which frame is an I frame.  In each sequence the "pict_type=" value changes.  I was wondering if there was a way for me to use AWK to input an iteration number and output the preceding pkt_pts_time value where the pict_type value equals I.

For instance, if my frame number is 3.  I would be able to enter the number 3 and the awk expression would go to the third [Frame] to [/Frame] sequence and then look back from there till it found a "pict_type=I" string.  Then it would see that the pkt_pts_time for that sequence iteration was "pkt_pts_time=0.00000" and it would output 0.0000

Comment: Did you generate this text file? Because you can output only I-frame data and avoid having to post process it.

Comment: It would be super helpful if you include the code you've written for this so far. Much easier to help you figure out how to fix your code if we can see your code.

Comment: @ghoti, here is my code.   ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames -show_entries
frame=pkt_pts_time,pict_type,frame_number -v quiet
input.mp4

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I need to count frames, though, so if I only include I-frame data I don't count the frames correctly.  As far as I have searched, you can't output the frame number in FFProbe.

Comment: @dne202, that totally sounds relevant to your question. I recommend you [include it in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47105443/edit) Comments provide terrible formatting, and are often missed/ignored when people are trying to determine what needs to be answered.

Comment: @ghoti, Added to the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this. I will explain how it works, if it does that you want.
I count frames by ending tag - `[/FRAME]`, but it can be changed to the starting tag `[FRAME]`.

```
awk -F '=' -v frame_number=3 '
$1 == "[/FRAME]" {
    frame_cnt++;    
}
$1 == "pkt_pts_time" {
    tmp_time = $2;
}
$2 == "I" {
    i_time = tmp_time;
}
frame_cnt == frame_number {
    print i_time;
    exit;
}' input.txt
```

**The version with the frame number after the I frame:**

```
awk -F '=' -v frame_number=3 '
$1 == "[/FRAME]" {
    frame_cnt++;    
}
$1 == "pkt_pts_time" {
    tmp_time = $2;
}
$2 == "I" {
    i_time = tmp_time;
    i_frame_number = frame_cnt + 1;
}
frame_cnt == frame_number {
    print "The I frame time = " i_time;
    print "The I frame number + 1 = " i_frame_number + 1;
    exit;
}' input.txt
```

**This version prints lower and upper "I" frame values, nearest to the target frame:**

```
awk -F '=' -v frame_number=3 '
# The frame counter - each time the first field of the line 
# equals to the [FRAME] string, the counter increments.

$1 == "[FRAME]" {
    frame_cnt++;    
}
# The "tmp_time" variable is updated each time the "pkt_pts_time" occurs.
# So, it does not have fixed value, it changing each time - floating.

$1 == "pkt_pts_time" {
    tmp_time = $2;
}
# Here we are determining the nearest "I" frame, before the target frame.
# It works this way: each time the "I" frame occurs, the "i_lower" value
# updated. It happens, while we are not reach the target frame. Then, it is 
# last time, whey the "i_lower" variable is updated. So, we found the nearest
# "I" frame before the target frame.

frame_cnt <= frame_number && $2 == "I" {
    i_lower = tmp_time;
}
# Here, we are determining the nearest "I" frame, after the target frame.
# When it occurs, the lower and upper "I" frame values are printed
# and the script execution stops.
# Note, that if the upper "I" frame does not exist, the script will print nothing,
# because, the condition returns false.

frame_cnt >= frame_number && $2 == "I" {
    print "lower I = " i_lower;
    print "upper I = " tmp_time;
    exit;
}' input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, @MiniMax !  This works perfectly.  To get it to give me the frame count of the I frame after, what would I need to change?

Comment: @dne202 It is easy, just add the `I` frame number variable into the `I` checking section. I did it already, see the answer update.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say how do I get the same output from the top script, but of the I frame following the inputed frame_number?  Also, I'd love the explanation since you offered :)

Comment: @dne202 That is, you want put the frame number, for example `3`,  and get the nearest 'I' frame time before it and the nearest 'I' frame time after it. In other words, I frames are like range borders - the upper `I` frame and the lower `I` frame with the `3` frame in between. Correct?

Comment: That is correct.  Also, out of curiosity, is there a way to get the `pkt_pts_time` of the frame prior to the previous `I` frame?  I know I could do it by storing the `i_frame_number` and subtracting 1 and then running some more code, but I was wondering if there was a way to build it into this code.  Just curious, I am in awe of awk!

Comment: @dne202 I added the new script version with comments. It do, what we were discussed in our previous comments - prints the nearest `I` frame time before target frame and the nearest `I` frame time after it. You can ask, if you have a question about how the script works.

Comment: @dne202 What about your last question "is there a way to get the `pkt_pts_time` of the frame prior to the previous I frame" - yes, it is possible. As an example, you can store all `pkt_pts_time` values in the array `pts_time_arr[frame_cnt]` and then print `pts_time_arr[i_frame_number - 1]` in the end.

Answer (score 1):

another `gawk` using record structure

```
$ awk RS='\\[/FRAME\\]' '/pict_type=I/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                                         if($i~/pkt_pts_time/) 
                                           {time=$i; break}};
                          NR==3 {split(time,t,"="); print t[2]; exit}'
```

store the time for given type, when it's third record print the latest seen.

Answer (score 0):

It SOUNDS like this is what you're asking for but it won't produce any output from your sample input given you want something related to frame 3 because nothing in your sample input meets your requirements as I understand them:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="=" }
$1=="[FRAME]" { ++frameNr }
{ frame[$1] = $2 }
$1=="[/FRAME]" {
    if ( frameNr == n ) {
        if ( frame["pict_type"] == "I" ) {
            print frame["pkt_pts_time"]
        }
    }
    delete frame
}

$ awk -v n=3 -f tst.awk file

$ awk -v n=5 -f tst.awk file
0.959292
```

Anyway hopefully it's obvious enough what it's doing that you can massage it to suit if it's not exactly what you need.